# Query with db.CurrentOp() for Mongo DB idle connections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below query gives the results of all the operations in progress including idle connections:

```
db.currentOp(true)
```

Below query gives the result for the connections which are active only.

```
db.currentOp({
 "active" : true,})
```

I am looking for a query to find all the inactive (or idle connections). I have already tried below query and it doesn't return the idle connections I have.

```
db.currentOp({
 "active" : false,})
```

Comment: To improve the question quality you should put the snippets in code sections.

Comment: Thanks @Mush I have edited the question